# Count metric induced topologies on countable set.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

How many topologically distinct metrizations of countable set are there? One can find countably many different ones by arranging points on a plane for example. Are there more than that? How would one approach this?

Comment: Technically, arranging points in the plane may still induce the same topology (discrete, for instance).

Comment: I'm aware of that. You can get distinct topologies by having different number of accumulation points for instance. That's why I'm asking for topologically distinct not just metrically

Comment: Well spotted @YuiTo Cheng. More of a special case than duplicate, still solves the problem. :)